# Quality Audit Software applied to Free Software

Tags: testing, audit, software-quality

I'm doing an investigation searching for quality audit software applied to free software but haven't not much luck so far. I already found information of software that make quality audit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_audit_tools but don't know if those applies to free software too.

Any idea or information in this matter will be very useful.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The article you linked to discusses the financial audit process. It is not about software quality. Are you asking a question about software quality "audits"? If so, please be more specific about what you mean by "quality audit". I've been in the industry for 35 years, and have never knowingly been involved in a "quality audit".

Comment: If this is about "software quality audit" software, this probably belongs on [sqa.se]. If it is for quality "financial audit" software, then it probably belongs on [money.se]. In either case, I don't think it's appropriate for SO unless you're having a problem with your algorithm for writing your own or something. :-)

Comment: Go to check out the Software Quality Assurance, maybe i'll have success.

Answer (score 1):

From experience working with [CAAT](http://www.auditware.co.uk/content/76/The-need-for-CAATs) technology, [IDEA software](http://www.auditware.co.uk/content/70/ideav9) has been the strongest by far, but it is not free. I'm sure there is some free software, but it will be poor quality.

Answer (score 0):

There's the annual Open Source Code Quality report, which seems to be the most relevant document.

**References**

- [Projects Audited by Coverity Scan](http://scan.coverity.com/projects)
- [2013 Coverity Scan Report(pdf)](http://softwareintegrity.coverity.com/rs/coverity/images/2013-Coverity-Scan-Report.pdf)
- [2012 Coverity Scan Report(pdf)](http://wpcme.coverity.com/wp-content/uploads/2012-Coverity-Scan-Report.pdf)